# How do they know their velocity in a spaceship?

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, velocity, space-travel

Suppose a spaceship is going to Mars or to Jupiter, they switch on their thrusters and accelerate for a certain period, how to they know their position / velocity, do they refer to the Sun?

Comment: This is really to do with the navigation of spacecraft?  http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-space-probes-navig/

Comment: Their speed *with respect to what*? Also, why can't they simply monitor how long they accelerate with what acceleration?I'm not sure what the question is here.

Comment: No, Farcher's answer tells me *one possible interpretation of this question* (a charitable one). It should not be left up to the answerer to figure out and restate your question in clearer terms.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, from Farcher's link : " The accurate navigation of space probes depends on four factors: First is the measurement system for determining the position and **speed** of a probe"  .... *intelligenti pauca*! :) , no worries, someone might upvote my question, they usually have!

Comment: I would really like to say that you may want to remove the use of the word propellers. A better word would be thrusters.

Comment: I understood the question just fine but was having a hard time imagining there being air or water all the way from Mars to Jupiter. :-)   Thanks for making the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you are asking is the position, velocity and acceleration of a space probe relative to the ever changing positions of the components which make up the Solar system?  In the article cited below it describes the coordinate system as follows

"Calculation of the trajectory of a space probe requires the use of an inertial coordinate system as well, wherein a grid is laid over the solar system and fixed relative to the star background."

[This article describes how navigation is achieved for deep space probes](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-space-probes-navig/), the accuracy of which can be astonishing - "Cassini's location is typically determined to a kilometer or less relative to Saturn".  All this with the time delay between ground control and the probe.

Comment: As things stand this remains primarily a pointer to off-site resources, with little of the answer summarized locally.